# Python encoding '\xdf' / '\xc3\x9f' to 'ß'

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm downloading the html of one site and prettify it with beautiful soup like this:

```
f_page_soup = Soup(f_driver.page_source, "lxml")
with open(f_filename_pretty, 'wb') as f_output:
    f_output.write(f_page_soup.prettify(encoding='utf-8'))
```

and open the prettified html like this:

```
ecjData = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
    pageSoup = Soup(ecjData, "lxml")
```

Inside the html are different links that I want to collect with BeautifulSoup. One of them looks like this `example.com/weiß/3`

After iterating over all the links I want to print them. Doing this:

```
print ("https://example.com" + a["href"])
```

gives me a `UnicodeEncodeError` for the link above as expected.

So after catching the error I try to decode it:

```
print (("https://example.com" + a["href"]).encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1'))
```

which results in

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 78-79: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Another approach I tried, was to replace inside the string:

```
print (str(("https://example.com" + a["href"]).encode('utf-8')).replace('\\xc3\\x9f','ß'))
```

which then leads again to:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xdf' in position 80: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Basically what I need to be printed is:

```
"https://example.com/weiß/3"
```

How can I achieve this?
I'm using python 3.5.

Comment: This is missing some very key information. Which version of python is this? And what is `a` and `a['href']`? And what is the full traceback of the `UnicodeEncodeError`?

Comment: This mostly pertains to PEP 529: Change Windows filesystem encoding to UTF-8, which has been introduced in version 3.6 and above.